# ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'telegram'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a telegram bot. The code i am trying to execute is :

```
from telegram import ParseMode
```

But it is throwing up this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'telegram'
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)
```

Could you please advise how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to import with this way:

```
from telegram.ext import ParseMode
```

---

if problem not solved:

install the package like this:

> pip install python_telegram_bot

or

> pip install "python_telegram_bot==12.4.2"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'telegram.ext'`

Comment: did you try to install last version of `telegram`? or uninstall the package and install that with this commands? `pip install python_telegram_bot`

Comment: I installed it and it imported in well

Comment: i used `pip install telegram` and i was able to import `import telegram.ext` just not parsemode. Should i uninstall it ?

Comment: yes uninstall the `telegram` and install `python_telegram_bot`

Comment: i uninstalled it and install `python_telegram_bot` but i am still getting the same message. Just to be sure also restarted the kernal

Comment: This answer is misleading at least. [`ParseMode` ](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.parsemode.html) is clearly not contained in the `telegram.ext` package. Also `python-telegram-bot` is by now on version 13.7. Older versions don't get bug fixes and v13 introduced breaking changes. Finally, the project is named `python-telegram-bot`, not `python_telegram_bot`. While `pip` apparently converts `_` to `-` due to naming conventions, this may not be the case with other package managers or future pip versions. Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of PTB.

Answer (score 16):

as per Version 20 you need to use:

```
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
```

Answer (score 0):

Was confronted with this recently, and what worked for me is:

```
from telegram import ParseMode
```