# Aiogram issue: ParseMode

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
(venv) legion@LittleKid:~/Projects/FacialRecognition/api$ python3 tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legion/Projects/FacialRecognition/api/tests.py", line 172, in <module>
    from aiogram.types import ParseMode
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'aiogram.types' (/home/legion/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/types/__init__.py)
(venv) legion@LittleKid:~/Projects/FacialRecognition/api$
```

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = '6195275934:AAEngBypgfNw3SwcV9uV_jdatZtMvojF9cs'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    view_button = InlineKeyboardButton("View service addresses", callback_data='view_addresses')
    suggest_button = InlineKeyboardButton("Suggest service", callback_data='suggest_service')
    keyboard.add(view_button, suggest_button)

    welcome_text = "Welcome to the car service chat!\n\nHow can I help you today?"
    await message.reply(welcome_text, reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'view_addresses')
async def view_addresses(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Logic to retrieve service addresses and show on Google Maps
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Viewing service addresses on Google Maps...")


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'suggest_service')
async def suggest_service(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    welcome_text = "Welcome to the car service chat!\n\nPlease provide details about the service you want to suggest."
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, welcome_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69155789/importerror-cannot-import-name-parsemode-from-telegram